# Can't make DREDD to use the schema.example as POST body

Tags: dredd

I'm trying to use Dredd to test my OpenAPI specified API but I can't get Dredd to recognize the JSON body of my POST requests, it keeps sending my POST requests with an empty body.
According to Dredd's [documentation](https://dredd.org/en/latest/how-it-works.html#id8) it uses the schema.example for "in": "body" and that's exactly what I am doing but Dredd keeps issuing the POST with empty body.

I've tried both OpenAPI3 and OpenAPI2 with the same result. My POST operation in OpenAPI2 specification looks like this:

```
  /availableCounters:
    post:
      summary: Get the available counters for a specified time range
      description: This API returns the available counters for the specific time range requested.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              properties:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/definitions/property_spec'
        '400':
          description: 'Could not retrieve available Counters: ${error}'
      parameters:
        - required: true
          name: body
          in: body
          schema:
            example: {"searchSpan": {"from": {"dateTime": "2019-01-20T21:50:37.349Z"},"to": {"dateTime": "2019-01-22T21:50:37.349Z"}}}
            type: object
            properties:
              searchSpan:
                $ref: '#/definitions/from_to'
```

But when I use Dredd to test this OpenAPI definition, for this operation it doesn't send the body as it should:

```
request:
method: POST
uri: /availableCounters
headers:
    User-Agent: Dredd/8.0.0 (Windows_NT 10.0.17134; x64)

body:



expected:
headers:

statusCode: 200
bodySchema: {"type":"object","properties":{"properties":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/property_spec"}}},"definitions":{"property_spec":{"type":"object","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"type":{"type":"string","enum":["Double","String","DateTime"]}}}}}


actual:
statusCode: 400
headers:
    connection: close
    date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 23:22:09 GMT
    content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    server: Kestrel
    content-length: 96

bodyEncoding: utf-8
body:
Could not retrieve available Counters: TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchSpan' of undefined
```

I've tried using both schema.example and schema.x-example but Dredd will not send the body. As I've said previously I've also tried OpenAPI3 and I get the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is old, but the problem is still there: Dredd seems to ignore the body parameter, if the *consumes* field is missing.

So try:

```
/availableCounters:
  post:
    summary: Get the available counters for a specified time range
    consumes:
     - application/json
[...]
```

Comment: Even though I had a body parameter of schema `type: string` and an `example` value, without `consumes` with `text/plain`, Dredd would not send the body! Although to be fair, it does output the problem, just not with a clear action to fix: `fail: headers: At '/content-type' No enum match for: "application/problem+json"`